# Button with type reset not working for ASP.NET Core select tag helper

Tags: html, forms, asp.net-core, reset, asp.net-core-tag-helpers

I have a form with a button with type "reset". But after clicking it, it doesn't reset the `select` tag helper items. How can I solve it in the practical and easiest way?

I'm using ASP.NET Core 7 and this is the form inside my `.cshtml` file:

```
<form asp-area="admin" asp-controller="course" asp-action="index" method="get" id="filter-form">
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="PageIndex" />
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="PageSize" />

    <div class="mb-3">
        <label class="form-label"> Title:</label>
        <input asp-for="Title" class="form-control">
    </div> 

    <div class="mb-3">
        <label class="form-label"> Age Category:</label>
        <select class="form-select" asp-for="AgeCategory" asp-items="Html.GetEnumSelectList<AgeCategoryEnum>()"></select>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="reset" class="btn btn-warning">
            <i class="bi bi-repeat"></i>
            reset
        </button>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Filter</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

**Edit:**

When URL has no query params, the reset button works. (e.g. https://localhost:44331/admin/course). but when you have filtered the form once before and click the reset button, it doesn't work!(e.g. https://localhost:44331/admin/course?PageIndex=1&PageSize=10&AgeCategory=1)

Comment: I test your code, and it can  reset the select tag helper items, like :https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVwAt.gif , you can use `F12` to see if any error message in the console tab.

Comment: you are right, maybe I explained my problem in a not clear way. now I edit my question and have explained more detail about it. @QingGuo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change the button `type="reset"` to  `type="button"`

like :

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" onclick="ResetFormWithJS()">
     <i class="bi bi-repeat"></i>
     reset
 </button>
 <script>
    function ResetFormWithJS() {
      
        document.getElementById("Title").value = "";//  reset Title
        document.querySelector('#filter-form select').selectedIndex = 0;// reset Select
       
    }
</script>
```

result:
[image]

Comment: Thanks. with some changes it works. I use this method: `function resetForm() {
    document.querySelectorAll("#filter-form input[type=text]").forEach(i => i.value = null)
    document.querySelectorAll("#filter-form select").forEach(s => s.selectedIndex = 0);
}`

Answer (score 0):

The `type="reset"` button in HTML forms resets the form elements to their initial values as defined. However, the `select` tag's items generated by `asp-items="Html.GetEnumSelectList<AgeCategoryEnum>()"` are not directly controlled by HTML attributes. So you can use JavaScript to reset the select element.

```
<button type="reset" class="btn btn-warning" onclick="resetForm()">
    <i class="bi bi-repeat"></i>
    reset
</button>

<script>
    function resetForm() {
        // Reset the form
        document.getElementById('filter-form').reset();

        // Reset the select element to its first option
        document.querySelector('#filter-form select').selectedIndex = 0;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, but please check the Edit section of my question. your answer not support it too.